# Wildfly 10 load balancing Issue

Tags: jboss, load-balancing, wildfly

We have been able to deploy two load-balancing servers in a QA environment.  However, when attempting to cluster the servers in another QA environment, the session state is no longer being passed between these servers.  Does anyone have any idea what could be a possible issue?

Comment: I am having similar issue for JBoss EAP 7. You can also refer to my question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43454068/load-balancing-cluster-not-working-with-apache-http-server-2-4-6-and-jboss-eap-7